# Get video file from flash player objective-c

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, vk

Does anybody knows how to get url to video file from this url:

http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=6492&id=141771975&hash=a984f2edb68fc4f7

It returns flash player with video, but iphone doesn't support flv format, and i want to know if video is flv or mp4 file. If someone know how to play flv video online, i'm listnening :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an HTTP traffic sniffer/proxy to see what files get loaded by the page. Many browsers have it built into their developer tools (e.g. the net tab in Firebug), but I prefer to use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) which has many other useful features for web developers.

Using Charles, I can see that the file that is loaded when I click play is http://cs12326.vk.com/u06492/video/ab94044f46.flv, which is an FLV file.

**EDIT:** If you want to do this programmatically, you might be out of luck because only the video player (implemented in Flash) knows from which URL to retrieve the video file. You could reverse-engineer it for this particular website (see below) but it will obviously only work for videos on vk.com, and perhaps not even all videos on vk.com.

Looking at the HTML I can see that there are four seemingly important javascript variables being defined:

```
var video_host = 'http://cs12326.vk.com/';
var video_uid = '06492';
var video_vtag = 'ab94044f46';
var video_no_flv = 0;
```

These values can be found in the video URL, so it's safe to assume that by parsing the HTML text for these variable definitions, and using the values to compile a URL, you can be able to find the file.

I'm assuming that the `video_no_flv` variable that is defined in the same piece of code indicates whether the video is an FLV file or not. In this page it's set to `0`, so I'm assuming that means that it is an FLV file. That would mean that by searching through the HTML text string for the sub-string `video_no_flv` and parsing the integer after the next subsequent `=` will tell you whether the video file is an FLV file or not.

If it isn't, it's safe to assume that it's a MP4/F4V (both of which are different suffixes for the same type of MPEG-4 H.264 file) and that you should be able to play it on your iPhone. If that's the case, you should be able to compile the URL from the pieces mentioned above and load it.

```
//Pseudo-code
url = video_host + video_uid + "/video/" + video_vtag + ".m4v"
```

To assess whether this will really work, you will need to investigate a larger collection of videos on that site.

Also, note that to implement knowledge that you have gained through this type of reverse engineering, and to display the videos outside of the context in which they have been published, might break that website's terms of service and could be an act of felony.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I should have figured that's what you wanted, because this is a programming site after all (even though you didn't explicitly state that you wanted to write a program to perform this check.) Editing my response.

Comment: The title of question: Get video file from flash player objective-c :)

Comment: Have edited my answer, adding an idea on how to solve this programmatically.